# How to deal with trailing garbage caused from unzipping the hs37d5 fastq file

Tags: java, gzip, picard

I have really tried to sort this problem out but it seems like no one else faced this problem before. I unzipped the fastq file from the 1000G:

```
gunzip -c **hs37d5.fa.gz** | awk '{if(NR%4==1) {printf(">%s\n",substr($0,2));} else if(NR%4==2) print;}' > ref.fa
```

The unzipped folder though, has some "trailing garbage" and it causes the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" picard.PicardException: Sequence name appears more than once in reference: NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN"

when trying to run:

```
java -jar picard.jar CreateSequenceDictionary R=ref.fasta O=ref.dict
```

If someone could give me a little help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are extracting a fasta file but are using `NR%4` which would be used for a fastq file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I use gunzip -ct hs37d5.fa.gz > tmp.fa in order to also test the fasta file, it provides me with an empty output.

Comment: to get any useful help, please create a minimal verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve